# Combine results from two tables into one recordset

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables items and content.

```
 items:|ID|menu|img
```

table

```
 itemcontent |ID|parent|title|content
```

content holds is paired to items by parent holding the title and content

i want to search all the items and also print out those records wich do not have a title present in the itemcontent table
whereby the titles will be printed as "Empty".
so printing out the output would look something like:

```
title: test1 and ID: items.ID=1
title: Empty and ID: items.ID=2
title: Empty and ID: items.ID=3
title: test2 and ID: items.ID=4
title: Empty and ID: items.ID=5
etc...
```

I tried the following and then some but to no avail:

```
SELECT items.*, itemcontent.title, itemcontent.content
FROM items, itemcontent
WHERE itemcontent.title LIKE '%$search%'
     AND itemcontent.parent = items.ID 
order by title ASC
```

A little help would be much appreciated

Comment: Please add some tags like "SQL" or "Access" or "Oracle" or whatever so we understand what you're using

Comment: Your query looks ok. What happens when you run it?

Comment: what database engine are you using?

Comment: Joel is SQL meant to be the language or the malaprop for SQL SERVER?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want all the rows from items whether or not they have a match in itemcontent, plus a field from itemcontent when there is a match you need to use an OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT items.*, COALESCE(itemcontent.title, 'empty'), itemcontent.content
FROM items LEFT OUTER JOIN itemcontent ON itemcontent.parent = items.ID 
 WHERE (itemcontent.title LIKE '%$search%' OR itemcontent.title IS NULL)
 ORDER BY items.ID, itemcontent.title ASC
```

There are small differences among SQL dialects (for instance, not all versions have COALESCE) so if you want a more precise answer indicate which product you're using.

Comment: Works like a charm! thank you i solved it by updating the item table with the itemcontent values that worked too this seems more elegant though ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure you might want to ORDER BY itemcontent.title and not just title or select itemcontent.title AS title? Do you have a field called title in the items table?