# Combine data from two tables with one taking precedence

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to merge the data from two tables into one result but without duplicating id's in the `CourseID` with the user's completions taking precedence in the results.

#### User Course Completion Table

```
Col Name        | Default | PK?
===================================
UserID                      Y
CourseID                    Y
SystemComplete    NULL      N
UserComplete      NULL      N

UserID, CourseID, SystemComplete, UserComplete
1, 1, NULL, 12/06/2012
1, 2, NULL, 12/06/2012
1, 3, 10/06/2012, 12/06/2012
1, 4, NULL, NULL
1, 5, 10/06/2012, NULL
2, 1, NULL, 12/06/2012
```

#### Course to Group table

```
Col Name        | Default | PK?
===================================
CourseID                     Y
GroupID                      Y

CourseID, GroupID
1, 1
2, 1
3, 1
4, 1
12, 1
5, 2
6, 2
```

#### Expected results

I want to find all of the course completions for a user and supplement that list with the uncompleted items. For example, if I want the list for Group `1` and User `1`, I would get

```
CourseID, SystemComplete, UserComplete
======================================
1, NULL, 12/06/2012
2, NULL, 12/06/2012
3, 10/06/2012, 12/06/2012
4, NULL, NULL
12, NULL, NULL --not in completion record
```

#### What I've tried

I have tried several queries but I can't seem to figure this out. The one below was something I found in [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493896/combine-results-from-two-tables-into-one-recordset) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11059372/oracle-sql-combining-two-tables-but-taking-duplicates-from-one).

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(uc.CourseID, cg.CourseID) as CourseID
FROM
  CoursesToGroup as cg
FULL JOIN UserCompletion as uc ON
  uc.CourseID = cg.CourseId
WHERE
  uc.UserID = 1 AND
  cg.GroupID = 1
```

...but this only returns a one row result

The closest I have gotten is `UNION`ing two queries but then I can't figure out how to get the `UserComplete` and `SystemComplete` data into the query

```
SELECT CourseID
FROM UserCompletion
WHERE
  EmployeeID = 1

UNION

SELECT CourseID
FROM CoursesToGroup
WHERE
  LearningPathID = 1
```

This one will return the proper results for the `CourseID` but, as I stated previously, I can't figure out how to drop the completion data in there and still remove duplicate `CourseId`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CourseID, SystemComplete, UserComplete
FROM UserCompletion
WHERE
UserId = 1

UNION

SELECT CourseId, null, null
FROM CoursesToGroup
where GroupId = 1
and CourseId NOT IN 
    (SELECT CourseId From UserCompletion
     WHERE UserId = 1)
```